# Count number of rows with similar times

Tags: sql, postgresql

good afternoon. What is the point, the train has a geotag that determines its position in space. Location data is entered into a table. It is required to calculate how many times the train was at a certain point. But the problem is that being at a certain point, the geotag leaves several entries in the table by time. I wrote a query that allows you to count the number of arrivals, but the problem is that it works if you take only one train in the selection of values, and if you take several entries in a row, the query already counts incorrectly. Below I will attach a table and a written query

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7dlr.png)

[query1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQwTV.png)

if you select several train numbers, the values ​​are confused and are considered as one

Now I have this request, it counts the number of arrivals, but it counts incorrectly, if instead of several trains you specify only one in the selection, everything will be correct, what is my mistake ???
[query2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSTva.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use group by for address and zone.
By "train"| you mean adress?